# Search query not working in Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg

I have a search working fine in development as seen here
 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIt15.jpg

but it is not returning anything in production with the pg database 
https://www.luminoto.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chicago+skyline

Here is my basic search function

```
def self.search(search)
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
  active.where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR id_num LIKE ?", search_condition, search_condition, search_condition)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: your development and production db aren't the same and they might not have the same data. Maybe that's the reason why you're not getting anything back in prod.

Answer (score 0):

For PG you might be better off using 'ILIKE' over 'LIKE':

```
def self.search(search)
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
  active.where("title ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ? OR id_num ILIKE ?", search_condition, search_condition, search_condition)
end
```

I know you've probably fixed the problem given it's been a few years, but I always forget about this and spend ages trying to figure out why my search forms don't work in production on heroku.